# Wrong input code for complex input

Tags: c++, c, input, format, buffer

I need to read these data from the console but it gets weird. Please check it out, because I am stuck for few hours. Thanks in advance. The problem is that the variavle **smer** have crazy content or not at all.

```
3
3 5
2 2 S
8
DPLDLPDD
2 4 Z
7
PDDPDPD
2 1 J
8
PPDLDDDD
```

Here is my reading code

```
int N;
scanf("%d", &N);
for (int g = 0;g < N; g++)
{
    int velX, velY;
    scanf("%d %d", &velX, &velY);

    int x, y;
    char smer = 'A';
    scanf("%d %d %c", &x, &y, &smer); getchar();

    int D;
    scanf("%d", &D); //getchar();

    bool killed = false;
    int oldX = x, oldY = y;
    string dstr;
    for (int i = 0; i < D; i++)
    {
        char c;
        scanf("%c", &c);
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Declare a data structure (pseudo code)

Comment: `int velX, velY;
    scanf("%d %d", &velX, &velY);` move to before for-loop, `//getchar();` -->  `getchar();`

Comment: so stupid mistake, thanks :)

Comment: Consider http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer